# How to connect a Mac with Mini DisplayPort to an old TV

Tags: mac, tv, display-adapter

I have a MacBook with a Mini DisplayPort and I'm trying hook it up to my old TV. The TV has the following sockets:

- [S-Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video)
- [RCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector)
- [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART)

What sort of setup would be needed to use the TV as a monitor. I'm not looking for a sharp image like what you'd expect of a monitor, just enough to watch VGA size videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from what I've read that buying a mini displayprot to vga and vga to S-Video will not work. [Here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1752866&start=15&tstart=0)'s a related thread on Apple's forums. Users there say [this](http://sewelldirect.com/pc-to-tv.asp) thing works.

Comment: I have an old DisplayPort to RCA adapter. Would getting a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter between them work, or do the connectors work somehow fundamentally differently?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but I think that it should work.